# HTML Select returning user-visable text not value field

Tags: html, select, asp-classic

I am having an issue with a SELECT tag in an HTML form on an ASP page. This will have varying numbers of options under it, and is generated dynamically from a database. Code below;

```
<select name='select1' id='select1' size='10'>
    <option value="12345678901234567890">User-Friendly Text 1</option>
    ...
    <option value="10000039373766232452">Text 2</option>
</select>
```

The issue is that when this form is submitted to the next asp page, the value returned is 'Text 2' for example, or 'User-Friendly Text 1'. Can anyone explain why the text is being submitted and not the value of the select? I need the value more than the text!!

I've narrowed own the issue to this bit of JavaScript

```
var lb = document.getElementById('fb_friend');
arrTexts = new Array();
for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
    arrTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text;
}
arrTexts.sort();
for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
    lb.options[i].text = arrTexts[i];
    lb.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];
}
```

The line `lb.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];` is causing the issue here.

Comment: Can you include the asp code to pull the value?

Comment: Just a guess: Is it related to the missing ' for the size-attribute?

Comment: The asp code is using an httpwebrequest and then using a json parser to generate the output in a loop.

Comment: The missing ' is a typo when putting the code on here! Sorry.

Comment: I've worked out that the issue is related to the java below;
<script language='JavaScript' type='text/javascript'>
var lb = document.getElementById('fb_friend');
arrTexts = new Array();
for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
arrTexts[i] = lb.options[i].text;
}
arrTexts.sort();
for(i=0; i<lb.length; i++)  {
lb.options[i].text = arrTexts[i];
lb.options[i].value = arrTexts[i];
}
</script>
When this code is removed, it works ok. This code is needed to sort the list alphabetically.

Comment: @Tom: If you figured out the answer, you can add it as an answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Well this shines a positive light on my first post... sorry guys. Removed the line of java that was changing the value. I think this is a sign that 16 hours of straight coding is enough now. Sorry!